# additional function parameter when value of other param eq to a value

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find an article that I saw about function parameters that allowed for a dynamic parameter when the value of a previously defined parameter equaled something. So far from what I think I understand of dynamic params or param sets its not what I am looking for or maybe I need a better example.

Trying to do something like this where `-DHCP` is a switch param that is only present when the `-Section` parameter equals the validset value of `DEVICESETTINGS`.

`Get-VeloEdgeConfig -Name "ORMYEDGES*" -EdgeState CONNECTED -Section DEVICESETTINGS -DHCP`

Any references or suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: well you can just declare dhcp as a optional parameter and then make your checks with validatescript or something like that. otherwise maybe parametersets is what you´re looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, with a combination of `ParameterSet` and `ValidateScript`

```
function Get-VeloEdgeConfig() {

    [cmdletbinding(
        DefaultParameterSetName='Default'
    )]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter()]
        [String]$Section,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Section')]
        [ValidateScript({ $Section -eq 'DEVICESETTINGS' })]
        [Switch]$DHCP
    )

    # Print out current ParameterSet Section
    $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
}

# Calling the function
Get-VeloEdgeConfig -Section DEVICESETTINGS -DHCP # Selection
Get-VeloEdgeConfig -Section SOMETHINGELSE -DHCP # throws an error
```

Comment: I will go with using a flavor of this. Thanks.